# Insert an entry in DynamoDB table with two conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Conditions:

1. (hashKey, rangekey) combination should not already exist in the table
2. Newly inserted range Key value must be one more than the maximum rangeKey till now.

I'm trying to use expectedValueAttribute specified here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExpectedAttributeValue.html

But I can only put one condition at a time. How to enforce both the conditions?

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expectedAttributes = ...
    .put(hashKey, new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))
    .put(rangeKey, new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))
    .build();
```

This satisfies only condition 1 above.

Comment: Have you tried the **Comparison Operator** something like this `ExpectedAttributeValue()
   .withValue(new AttributeValue().withN("20"))
                         .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT)` Please go to this example maybe this will help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-improved-conditional-writes-in-dynamodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot compare the maximum value of the existing range key without first querying for it, you will need to do this in two steps.

1) Get the item with the highest range key for your given partition key

2) Compare that returned range key with the one you have, if the returned key is exactly one less, put the new item. (Note you don't actually need to check whether the item already exists - as the query already confirmed it does not exist).

DynamoDB stores your items in range key order for a given partition, and it will also return your items for a given partition in this order. If your range key is a number, the sort order is numeric and you want the last result for your partition not the first. You can revere the order of your query using ScanIndexForward, then take the first item.

The query would be:

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("YOUR_TABLE");

QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("hash = :v_hash")
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
        .withString(":v_hash", "your_hash")
    .withScanIndexForward(false)
    .setMaxResultSize(1);

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);
```

If the item range key is one less than the new item range key, put the item. Note you should consider the behaviour if the items list is empty (i.e. the partition key does not exist yet).